# Selecting all corresponding fields using MAX and GROUP BY

Tags: sql, mysql, group-by, max, greatest-n-per-group

I have this table :

[image]

And I would like to make a request that would return for each `deal_id` the row with the highest `timestamp`, **and the corresponding `status_id`**.

So for this example, I would have returned 2 rows :

```
1226, 3, 2009-08-18 12:10:25
1227, 2, 2009-08-17 14:31:25
```

I tried to do it with this query

```
SELECT deal_id, status_id, max(timestamp) FROM deal_status GROUP BY deal_id
```

but it would return the wrong `status_id` :

```
1226, 1, 2009-08-18 12:10:25
1227, 1, 2009-08-17 14:31:25
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fetch the row which has the Max value for a column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121387/fetch-the-row-which-has-the-max-value-for-a-column)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

without a single primary key field, I think your best bet is:

```
select * from deal_status
inner join
  (select deal_id as did, max(timestamp) as ts
  from deal_status group by deal_id) as ds
  on deal_status.deal_id = ds.did and deal_status.timestamp = ds.ts
```

this still won't work if you allow having two different statuses for the same product at the same time

Comment: Your answer is almost perfect, you just need to put the `as ds` outside the parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i hope this gives what u want it

```
select deal_id,status_id, timestamp from deal_status 
inner join
  (select deal_id as did,max(timestamp) as ts
  from deal_status group by deal_id  )as ds
  on deal_status.deal_id = ds.did and deal_status.timestamp = ds.ts order by deal_id
```

Comment: the code you've written is essentially the same as the code in the accepted answer