# MySQL: Problem with max() and group by - wrong values

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a problem with a SQL statement:
Using this

```
select a.id as ID, a.dur as DUR, DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestampCol)) as date, 
 a_au.re as RE, a_au.stat as STAT from b_c
  inner join c on b_c.c_id = c.id
  inner join a on c.id = a.c_id
  inner join a_au on a.id = a_au.id
  inner join revi on a_au.rev = revi.rev
  where b_c.b_id = 5
```

I get this result:

```
ID  DUR         date   RE  STAT
-------------------------------
31, 10, '2010-07-14', 2200, 0
31, 10, '2010-07-14', 2205, 0
31, 10, '2010-07-14', 2206, 2
31, 10, '2010-07-14', 2207, 0
31, 10, '2010-07-14', 2210, 2
31, 10, '2010-07-15', 2211, 0
31, 10, '2010-07-14', 2213, 1
32, 10, '2010-07-14', 2203, 0
32, 10, '2010-07-14', 2204, 0
32, 10, '2010-07-14', 2208, 2
32, 10, '2010-07-14', 2209, 0
32, 10, '2010-07-15', 2212, 2
```

Now I want to get one result row for one ID and date combination. Also I want to get this result row with the highest RE number.

So I write my statement:

```
select a.id as ID, a.dur as DUR, DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestampCol)) as date, 
 max(a_au.re) as RE, a_au.stat as STAT from b_c
  inner join c on b_c.c_id = c.id
  inner join a on c.id = a.c_id
  inner join a_au on a.id = a_au.id
  inner join revi on a_au.rev = revi.rev
  where b_c.b_id = 5
  group by ID, date
```

Now I get this result:

```
ID  DUR         date   RE  STAT
-------------------------------
31, 10, '2010-07-14', 2213, 0
31, 10, '2010-07-15', 2211, 0
32, 10, '2010-07-14', 2209, 0
32, 10, '2010-07-15', 2212, 2
```

Everything seems to be okay, I have one result row per day/ID combination and the row with the highest RE number. But: the column STAT does not have the correct values!
The row

```
31, 10, '2010-07-14', 2213, 0
```

must have the status 1:

```
31, 10, '2010-07-14', 2213, 1
```

So there must be a mistake in my statement. It seems that MySQL takes the first STAT column value it found. But I want to have the corresponding one.

What should I do?
I saw other topics about this like here:
[Selecting all corresponding fields using MAX and GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305056/mysql-selecting-all-corresponding-fields-using-max-and-group-by)
but I can not transfer it to my SQL statement.

Thanks a lot in advance & Best Regards.

Comment: Added `greatest-n-per-group` tag.  Click on that tag to see dozens of other posts with similar problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT a.id as ID, 
       a.dur as DUR, 
       DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestampCol)) as date, 
       a_au.re as RE, 
       a_au.stat as STAT 
 FROM b_c
 JOIN c on b_c.c_id = c.id
 JOIN a on c.id = a.c_id
 JOIN a_au on a.id = a_au.id
 JOIN revi on a_au.rev = revi.rev
 JOIN ( SELECT a.id as ID, 
               DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestampCol)) as date, 
               MAX(a_au.re) as Max_RE
          FROM b_c
          JOIN c on b_c.c_id = c.id
          JOIN a on c.id = a.c_id
          JOIN a_au on a.id = a_au.id
          JOIN revi on a_au.rev = revi.rev
         WHERE b_c.b_id = 5 
      GROUP BY a.id, DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestampCol))) x ON x.id = a.id
                                                         AND x.date = DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestampCol))
                                                         AND x.max_re = a_au.re
WHERE b_c.b_id = 5
```

Sadly, MySQL doesn't support the WITH clause which could've made this a lot easier to read.

Comment: I used your SQL statement (I think it must be x.Max_Re = a_au.re instead of x.max_re = a_au.re). But now I get two rows with this data:
31, 10, '2010-07-14', 2213, 1
31, 10, '2010-07-14', 2213, 1
So I get the STAT 1 for ID 31 and REV 2213, but the other rows are missing and this row is there twice.

Comment: without "x on x.id ... ":
31, 10, '2010-07-14', 2200, 0
31, 10, '2010-07-14', 2205, 0
31, 10, '2010-07-14', 2206, 2
31, 10, '2010-07-14', 2207, 0
31, 10, '2010-07-14', 2210, 2
31, 10, '2010-07-15', 2211, 0
31, 10, '2010-07-14', 2213, 1
31, 10, '2010-07-14', 2200, 0
31, 10, '2010-07-14', 2205, 0
31, 10, '2010-07-14', 2206, 2
31, 10, '2010-07-14', 2207, 0
31, 10, '2010-07-14', 2210, 2
31, 10, '2010-07-15', 2211, 0
31, 10, '2010-07-14', 2213, 1
32, 10, '2010-07-14', 2203, 0
32, 10, '2010-07-14', 2204, 0
32, 10, '2010-07-14', 2208, 2
32, 10, '2010-07-14', 2209, 0
32, 10, '2010-07-15', 2212, 2

Comment: Add `group by 1, 2` to the `x` subquery.

Comment: Also, add `WHERE b_c.b_id = 5 ` at the end of the whole query.

Comment: @Tim: Corrected @ceteras: Thx, dunno how I forgot that.