# Return the data from the rows with the most recent date of each distinct candidate_id

Tags: mysql, group-by, max

I am attempting to return the data from the rows with the most recent date of each distinct candidate_id. It is correctly returning the most recent date (the created_unix column), but not the rest of the data from the corresponding row.

```
SELECT candidate_id, message, max(created_unix), jobpost_id, staffuserid 
    FROM messages 
       WHERE employer_id='$employerid' AND last='company' 
          GROUP BY candidate_id
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fetch the row which has the Max value for a column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121387/), [MySQL : selecting all corresponding fields using MAX and GROUP BY](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305056/mysql-selecting-all-corresponding-fields-using-max-and-group-by)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must `group by` everything not using an aggregate function:

```
SELECT candidate_id, message, max(created_unix), jobpost_id, staffuserid 
    FROM messages 
       WHERE employer_id='$employerid' AND last='company' 
          GROUP BY candidate_id, message, jobpost_id, staffuserid
```

If your `message` is different per row and you want to `group by candidate_id`, then you must not be using `message`. In that case, simply remove it from your select list and you won't need it in your `group by` list. The same goes for any other field you aren't using.

Remember, when using aggregate functions, you must contain each field in either an aggregate function or the `group by`. Otherwise, SQL won't know from which row to pull the data for the row returned.

**Update:**

After seeing what you're looking for, this will do the trick:

```
SELECT candidate_id, message, max(created_unix), jobpost_id, staffuserid 
    FROM messages 
       WHERE employer_id='$employerid' AND last='company' AND
       created_unix = (
           SELECT max(subm.created_unix)
           FROM messages subm
           WHERE subm.candidate_id = messages.candidate_id
       )
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Justin. Doing this will list out all rows (each row has a unique message). I only want one row per distinct candidate_id that meets there WHERE criteria. There isn't a need to group by jobpost_id or staffuserid as there is only 1 per candidate_id.

Comment: But there *is* a need to do that. When you use aggregate functions, for each field you return, you must either use it in an aggregate function or the `group by`. It sounds like you're not using the message field anyway, so just remove it from your `select` statement and you won't need it in your `group by`.

Comment: I am using the message field as I am printing it out in a table. My whole problem was that it was printing a message from the incorrect row (not the row containing the max of the created_unix) field.

Comment: I have updated my answer. It will pull the entire row that contains the max of the created_unix for that particular candidate_id.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll test this shortly. I looks like what I am looking for.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT m1.*
FROM messages as m1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN messages AS m2
    ON    (m1.candidate_id = m2.candidate_id
      AND (m1.created_unix < m2.created_unix)
WHERE m2.created_unix is NULL
AND employer_id='$employerid' AND last='company'
```

This joins `messages` to itself on candidate_id and makes rows with picks all dates in `m2` that are greater than each date in `m1`, substituting `NULL` if none are greater. So you get `NULL` precisely when there is no greater date within that `candidate_id`.