# Select the Most Recent Entry of Each Distinct Value in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

**Given a list of values with an unknown number of distinct string values, how do I get the most recent value of Each?**

I am given a list of objects with the following three properties: Balance, BalanceType, and CreatedDate.  Going in, I know there are a number of distinct values BalanceType can be set to, but I cannot be sure how many distinct values there are. For example, this is a valid input:

```
[{
 "BalanceType":"Cash",
 "Balance":350.03,
 "CreatedDate":10-20-16
},
{
 "BalanceType":"Cash",
 "Balance":250.01,
 "CreatedDate":10-20-15
},
{
 "BalanceType":"Cash",
 "Balance":450.21,
 "CreatedDate":10-20-14
},
{
 "BalanceType":"Securiites",
 "Balance":350.03,
 "CreatedDate":10-20-16
}]
```

As is the following:

```
[{
 "BalanceType":"Cash",
 "Balance":350.03,
 "CreatedDate":10-20-16
},
{
 "BalanceType":"Credit",
 "Balance":250.01,
 "CreatedDate":10-20-15
},
{
 "BalanceType":"LoanAmount",
 "Balance":450.21,
 "CreatedDate":10-20-14
},
{
 "BalanceType":"Securiites",
 "Balance":350.03,
 "CreatedDate":10-20-16
}]
```

I have already tried using the Max function to do this, but I discovered it only gives the maximum indicated value, not the object.  What am I missing?

[This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8611646/return-the-data-from-the-rows-with-the-most-recent-date-of-each-distinct-candida) is related, but in mysql so it isn't usable for me.

Comment: Sounds like you need to `GroupBy()`, then `OrderBy()` the date...

Comment: Also, I would edit your question to include actual code.  LINQ needs some objects to query against...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is helpful if you post data in `C#` format so it can be used directly. Translating your data, here are queries for your answer:

```
var src1 = new[] {
    new {
        BalanceType =  "Cash",
        Balance =  350.03,
        CreatedDate = new DateTime(2016, 10, 20)
    },
    new {
        BalanceType =  "Cash",
        Balance =  250.01,
        CreatedDate =  new DateTime(2015, 10, 20)
    },
    new {
        BalanceType =  "Cash",
        Balance =  450.21,
        CreatedDate =  new DateTime(2014, 10, 20)
    },
    new {
        BalanceType =  "Securiites",
        Balance =  350.03,
        CreatedDate =  new DateTime(2016, 10, 20)
    }
};
var src2 = new[] {
    new {
        BalanceType = "Cash",
        Balance = 350.03,
        CreatedDate = new DateTime(2016, 10, 20)
    },
    new {
        BalanceType = "Credit",
        Balance = 250.01,
        CreatedDate = new DateTime(2015, 10, 20)
    },
    new {
        BalanceType = "LoanAmount",
        Balance = 450.21,
        CreatedDate = new DateTime(2014, 10, 20)
    },
    new {
        BalanceType = "Securiites",
        Balance = 350.03,
        CreatedDate = new DateTime(2016, 10, 20)
    }
};


var ans1 = from r in src1
           group r by r.BalanceType into rg
           let latest = rg.Max(r => r.CreatedDate)
           select new { BalanceType = rg.Key, Balance = rg.Where(r => r.CreatedDate == latest).FirstOrDefault().Balance, CreatedDate = latest };

var ans2 = from r in src2
           group r by r.BalanceType into rg
           let latest = rg.Max(r => r.CreatedDate)
           select new { BalanceType = rg.Key, Balance = rg.Where(r => r.CreatedDate == latest).FirstOrDefault().Balance, CreatedDate = latest };
```

I assumed that if there were more than one latest dated `BalanceType`, it didn't matter which was chosen, so I used the first. If your `DateTime`s actually had times you could possibly replace `FirstOrDefault()` with `Single()` and crash your program if your assumption is wrong.

Comment: That's accurate, and probably why I was having so much trouble with it.  Thank you!