# How do I group by the MAX() in SQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql

Table:

```
+------------+------------------+
|     Number |       Date       |
+------------+------------------+
|          1 | 1900-01-01       |
|          1 | 2012-01-01       |
|          1 | 2011-01-01       |
|          2 | 1900-01-01       |
|          2 | 2007-01-01       |
+------------+------------------+
```

The result needs to be:

```
+------------+------------+
|     Number |    Date    |
+------------+------------+
|          1 | 2012-01-01 |
|          2 | 2007-01-01 |
+------------+------------+
```

and so on...

EDIT -

Table:

```
+------------+------------------+------------+
|     Number |       Date       |   Field3   |
+------------+------------------+------------+
|          1 | 1900-01-01       |     a      |
|          1 | 2012-01-01       |     b      |
|          1 | 2011-01-01       |     c      |
|          2 | 1900-01-01       |     a      |
|          2 | 2007-01-01       |     b      |
+------------+------------------+------------+
```

I want to SELECT the DISTINCT of Number WHERE it's GROUP's Date = MAX.

So after the query I would get:

```
1...b

2...b
```

Comment: Check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305056/selecting-all-corresponding-fields-using-max-and-group-by

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>You will need to use an aggregate function `max()` with a `GROUP BY`:</strike>

```
SELECT number, max(date)
from yourtable
group by number
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8e66b/3)

Depending on your database you can use `row_number()`:

```
select number, date
from
(
  select number, date,
    row_number() over(partition by number order by date desc) rn
  from yourtable
) src
where rn = 1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7435b/4).

This can also be written using a subquery:

```
select t1.*
from yourtable t1
inner join
(
  SELECT number, max(date) MaxDate
  from yourtable
  group by number
) t2
  on t1.number = t2.number
  and t1.date = t2.maxdate;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7435b/5)

Comment: what if I don't need to capture the Date? what if I need to run a select on all numbers WHERE MAX(date) for EACH?

Comment: @Rj. I don't understand what you are asking, can you clarify?  Both of these queries produce the result that you requested.

Comment: I want to do the same thing but I do NOT want to select the Date. I want to get all records where MAX(date). Let me try to rephrase: For each Number, I want to group it and then do a WHERE this GROUP has a MAX(date).

Comment: @Rj. can you edit your original post with more details, data?  I am missing something. Is your desired result not correct?

Comment: @Rj. See my edit, both the second and third version will still work.