# How to select a field corresponding to the tuple in which max(anotehrField) exists

Tags: mysql, sql

suppose i need to print

```
select field1,max(field2) from table1
```

here by field1 mean value of field1, whcih is correpsonding to tuple in the value at max(field2).

How can this be done?

for Example

```
 |  49 | 2000 |
 |  50 | 2001 |
 |  63 | 2002 |
 |  79 | 2003 |
```

Here the maximum value is 79, which is of year 2003, but the above select statement willreturn

`79 2000`

How can i get the output like

`79 2003`

This is an example, and i am looking for a generic method.

I know I could first use `order by` clause and then `limit 1`, or I can write a subquery like `Having abc >=All(some subquery)`,aint there any other method, which is less expensive?

Comment: @Exu check the modified question

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selecting all corresponding fields using MAX and GROUP BY](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305056/selecting-all-corresponding-fields-using-max-and-group-by)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are trying to find maximum value of a certain column based on some specific field value.There different ways of doing this. Try below query :-

```
SELECT article, dealer, price 
FROM   shop
WHERE  price=(SELECT MAX(price) FROM shop);
```

You can use above query for reference and make change in your query accordingly.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try This,

```
;With Cte as 
(
select max(F1)  mf from F
)
select f1,f2 from CTE 
inner join F on mf=f1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT MAX(field1) AS fld from table1) S 
Inner JOIN table1 T ON S.fld = T.field1
```